# comparing chars with MATLAB

Tags: matlab

```
[status ,list] = system(cmd)
```

this gives :

```
status = 
0 

list = 
RED
GREEN
BLUE
WHITE
type of list is 1x420 char

>>results = getListFromBlock(myFile)

results = 
RED
GREEN
BLUE
WHITE

results type 4x19 char
```

I want to check that list and results are equal which is the case but the comparison fail as variables haven't same type.
How could I convert each one to be able to make comparison ?

Thanks

Comment: I answered a fairly similar question coming from you a little while ago. Did you bothered checking it?

Comment: it seems that my question wasn't clear that's why I asked again diffrently with more detail.

Comment: the problem here isn't to use which function to compare, but how to convert these 2 variable to be able to compare

Comment: Would you say that the two results above (`list` and `results`) should compare equal?

Comment: Since there isn't a working example (see [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) I can't really play around with this on my own. For the second character array you should be able to convert it to a cell array using [`cellstr()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html), which will remove the whitespace padding automatically. For the first, my first thought is to utilize a [`regexp()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to strip the whitespace and generate a cell array of strings.

Comment: what is the pattern for regex ?

Comment: Without a test case I have no idea. Try `status_split = regexpi(status, '\S{1,}', 'Match')`

Comment: thanks excasa, this solves the problem, i'm really not familiar with regex pattern, would you please points me to any doc ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `results` the simplest option is to utilize a [`regexp()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) call to break your one long string into a cell array and discard the whitespace. See [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#inputarg_expression) for information on how to setup your expression.

For `list` you can use [`cellstr()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html) to break your character array into a cell array and strip the whitespace padding automatically. Because MATLAB arrays need to be rectangular, if want to have an array of characters with multiple rows each row needs to have the same number of characters, hence the whitespace padding.

```
% Generate the sorta really important sample data to work with
list = 'RED     ORANGE   YELLOW     GREEN     BLUE      INDIGO   VIOLET';
results = ['RED    '; ...
           'ORANGE '; ...
           'YELLOW '; ...
           'GREEN  '; ...
           'BLUE   '; ...
           'INDIGO '; ...
           'VIOLET '  ...
           ];

% Return cell array of groupings of non-whitespace chars(s), length >=1
results_cell = regexp(list, '\S{1,}', 'Match'); 

% Convert list into a cell array, strips whitespace padding
% Transpose to the same shape as results_cell
list_cell = cellstr(results).';
```

---

If we check out `whos` we have our data in a uniform format for comparison.

```
>> whos
  Name             Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  list             1x63              126  char               
  list_cell        1x7               856  cell               
  results          7x7                98  char               
  results_cell     1x7               856  cell
```